# Ionic 3 - Custom navigation history stack (Tabs, RootPages, ChildPages)

Tags: navigation, ionic3, back-button

Navigation in Ionic works like a simple stack, where new pages are pushed onto the top of the stack, which takes user forwards in the app and shows a back button. To go backwards, the top page is popped off. Since we set this.navCtrl in the constructor, we can call this.navCtrl.push(), and pass it the page we want to navigate to. We can also pass it an object containing data we would like to pass to the page being navigated to. Using push to navigate to a new page is simple.

But I want to achieve a functionality like below using overriding back(hardware) button :

1. When a page is loaded using this.navCtrl.setRoot(MyPage1) on a rootPage, by pressing hardware back button of device, previous rootPage should be loaded. How to track this navigation between roots?
2. When there is a tabbed navigation, previous active tab should be loaded if back button is pressed from device.

How to achieve this with ionic? Please guide.

Comment: can anyone please help?